# UIKit<-segue->SpriteKit memory leak

Tags: ios, swift

I enjoy Swift, iOS development.

I add a Segue between ViewController(for UIKit), and ViewController(for Spritekit).

I run iPhone Simulator, But memory navigator increase 30M per switch ViewController.

OSX 10.9.5, Xcode.6.1.1

1. New -> Project -> Game
2. New -> File -> Swift File -> FirstViewController.swift
3. Drag ViewController from library to storyboard, set Custom Class: FirstViewController
4. Set arrow to FirstViewController
5. Select FirstViewController, option&drag GameViewController(Segue)
6. Set identifier "toGame"
7. Select GameViewController, option&drag to self Exit
8. set identifier "back"

Code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func returnMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        println("back!")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toGame", sender: nil)
    }
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            scene.viewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should define a unwind segue to do "exit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
}
```

Thank you everyone!
Weak references!
memory leak solved!